# Run PHP calculator script inside wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, html, calculator

I have a calculator script which I want to run inside a wordpress blog, I have tried XYZ php code plugin and several others but they did not seem to work. I also tried loading the calculator part of the script from the server but this also did not seem to work.

The html form

```
 <form name="calc" action="?page=calc" method="POST">
      <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="bijvoorbeeld 15" name="value1" id="value1" type="text">
      <input class="u-full-width" placeholder="bijvoorbeeld 15" name="value2" id="value2" type="text">
      <select class="u-full-width" name="value3" id="value3">
        <option value="1">12 maanden</option>
        <option value="2">24 maanden</option>
        <option value="3">36 maanden</option>
        <option value="4">36 maanden</option>
      </select>
<input class="button-primary" value="Prijzen vergelijken" type="submit">
</form>
```

Initial php code after submitting the form

```
if($_GET['page'] == "calc"){
    $value1 = isset($_POST['value1']) ? $_POST['value1'] : '';
    $value2 = isset($_POST['value2']) ? $_POST['value2'] : '';
    $value3 = isset($_POST['value3']) ? $_POST['value3'] : '';
    $calculate = isset($_POST['calculate']) ? $_POST['calculate'] : '';
    if(empty($value1)){
        echo("Dit veld is verplicht!"); 

    } elseif(empty($value2)){ 
        echo("Dit veld is verplicht!");
    } elseif(empty($value3)){ 
        echo("Dit veld is verplicht!"); 
    } elseif(empty($calculate)){
        echo("Dit veld is verplicht!");
    } else{
        // If all inputboxes are not empty and the checkbox is ticked -> Calculate
        $calc->calculate($value1,$value2,$value3);
    }
}
```

Calculation part of the script (only a part since it produces a lot of results to keep it readable

```
class calc {
    function calculate($value1,$value2,$value3){

if(($value1 * $value2) > 136000){ $multiplier = 0.015; } 
elseif(($value1 * $value2) > 96000){ $multiplier = 0.0175; }
elseif(($value1 * $value2) > 48000){ $multiplier = 0.02; }
elseif(($value1 * $value2) > 24000){ $multiplier = 0.025; }
else{ $multiplier = 0.0275; }

        $result0 = $value3 * 12;
    etc.etc.etc.
```

I hope you guys know any solution or can point me in the right direction, as said troubleshooting the plugins did not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could use your script on a WordPress site. The proper one I believe would be to create a plugin to run it.

However if you are not comfortable creating plugins I believe a work around in this particular case could be to create a page template were you would include your code (all of it) and have the form submit to itself. Then you can create a regular WordPress page and set it to use that template you just created. You can learn more about creating WordPress page templates here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for you quick reply. I have tried several plug-ins but they did not work, they also did not gave any syntax errors. I would like to run the script in a wordpress post rather then a page so the editing template is my last solution. I was hoping there is a way to call the php script externally with the form but I do not know how to insert the scripts echo/response